# Transparency for QuickMapServices imagery in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, transparency-opacity, quickmapservices

Like 30 minutes ago I changed the transparency on a Google satellite image from QuickMapServices. I did this by just opening properties and there was a slider for transparency. Now, properties just shows metadata. I don't know what I switched or did differently.

How can I adjust the transparency of these layers?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the global opacity from the `layer properties -> Transparency -> Global opacity` as you can see below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I am just stupid. The properties window just happened to open in a way the the left half, with the different tabs (including transparency) was perfectly cut off on the edge of my screen. So it looked like the only thing was the web services tab.